# Get all posts of any post type in a category from REST API

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, rest-api

As far as I can tell in order to get custom posts in a specific category from the REST API the post type must be given e.g.:

`https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/customposttype?category=X`

Is there a way to get all the posts of any type in a given category without having to know the post type?

I see that [this can be done using a custom endpoint](https://allurewebsolutions.com/retrieve-post-type-wordpress-v2-rest-api-create-custom-endpoint) but that blog post was written 5 years ago and I'm wondering if it is now possible to do without resorting to that solution?

Comment: No, you'd still need to create a custom REST API endpoint, or if you just want the post ID, title and URL, then you can use the [Search Results endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/search-results/) (`wp/v2/search`) and the [`rest_post_search_query` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_post_search_query/) to filter the posts by specific categories. But what are you actually trying to do that requires this (get posts of any types in a specific category)?

Comment: > But what are you actually trying to do that requires this (get posts of any types in a specific category)?
I'm using the rest API as a data source for a custom frontend. I'm using the category hierarchy to build navigation so for a given category I only know its ID and not what post type it contains. I wanted to just get the posts by category and then decide how to render them based on the content. I have solved the issue for now by adding a custom field for post type to the category.

Comment: "*so for a given category I only know its ID and not what post type it contains*" - actually, if it's a term in the core `category` taxonomy, then you can use the Categories endpoint to fetch a category data *by ID*, e.g. `wp/v2/categories/123`, and then you'd get the links to the posts in each post type attached to the category taxonomy, where the links are stored in `_links['wp:post_type']` and a link might look like `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=123`.

Comment: You can also do the same for custom taxonomies, however, you'll need to know the route path of each taxonomy, e.g. `wp/v2/foo_tax`. Also, you can use the Taxonomies endpoint (`wp/v2/taxonomies`) to fetch the taxonomies on your site, which contains a `types` property containing the post types attached to the specific taxonomy.